# Overriding __hex__ in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, magic-methods

I have the following class:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class Proxy(object):
    __slots__ = ['_value']

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._value = obj

    def __hex__(self):
        return hex(self._value)

print(hex(42))
print(hex(Proxy(42)))
```

in Python 2.7 this prints

```
(py2.7) c:\hextest> python hextest.py
0x2a
0x2a
```

but in Py3.8 this raises an exception:

```
(py3.8) c:\hextest> python hextest.py
0x2a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hextest.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(hex(Proxy(42)))
TypeError: 'Proxy' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

what do I need to implement to make Proxy be interpreted as an integer?

Comment: As shown in [the docs for `hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex), you should define `__index__()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the goals of [PEP3100](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3100) (Miscellaneous Python 3.0 Plans) was to:

> [remove] `__oct__`, `__hex__`: use `__index__` in `oct()` and `hex()` instead.

To make this work, you need to implement `__index__`, likely as:

```
def __index__(self):
    # or self._value if you know _value is an integer already
    return operator.index(self._value)
```

You can see the commit that changed this behavior [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/cd16bf640405065e4702539632ce577536207d88):

> ```
> r55905 | georg.brandl | 2007-06-11 10:02:26 -0700 (Mon, 11 Jun 2007) | 5 lines
>
> Remove __oct__ and __hex__ and use __index__ for converting
> non-ints before formatting in a base.
>
> Add a bin() builtin.
> ```